# Arc Restrictions and Semantic issues using DDHotKey

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, hotkeys, ddhotkey

I'm trying to use DDHotKey for global hotkeys in a program I'm writing, however I can't get the program to compile because DDHotKeyCenter.m has errors.

The errors are below...
[image: errors]

I'm assuming this has something to do with my project settings, because the DDHotKey demo compiles and runs fine.

I've tried disabling arc, converting to arc, both with no success.

I'm still new to Cocoa, so I don't have any other ideas as to what could be causing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Errors when Arc is disabled...
[image: more errors]

Comment: Turn off ARC for DDHotKeyCenter class in Target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right - it looks like those files aren't ARC ready. However, if you're getting these messages then it means that the rest of your project is :)

Luckily, you can disable arc for specific files in your project.

In the build phases tab of the project settings, look at the compile sources section. Next to the files that are getting error (i.e. DDHotKeyCenter.m) add the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` - this will tell the compiler not to use ARC for this file only.

Just repeat that for each file complaining about `release`, `retain`, `autorelease` etc. and see how you get on.

Comment: As I mentioned, I've already tried disabling Arc. The result is 7 "Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error"s which are even harder to understand than the Arc errors.

Comment: Then you should add those errors to your question as well :) I assumed that you have disabled ARC for the entire project and were getting other ARC related errors!

Comment: Very well, I've updated my question with a screenshot of the errors. Hope you can help :)

Comment: That looks like you're compiling OK now but aren't linking with the library. In the settings page, in the 'link binary with libraries' section, make sure that you've chosen the DDHotKey library.

Comment: It wasn't the hotkey library that I needed to link, it was the carbon library. I linked it, and it compiled successfully. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I had to use `-fno-objc-arc` instead of `-lno-objc-arc`

Comment: @johndbritton oops, typo fixed. Sorry about that :)

Comment: @deanWombourne No worries, your answer still got me to the right solution.